# How to create a DAX cross-sectional measure?

Tags: dax

I don't know if I even worded the question correctly, but I'm trying to create a measure that depends on what is showing in the pivot table (using PowerPivot). In the image I posted, "DealMonth" is an expression in the PowerQuery table itself that simply takes the start date of the employee and subtracts it from the month a deal was closed in. That will show how long it took for that salesperson to close the deal. "TenureMonths" is also an expression in the PowerQuery table that calculates the tenure of the person. The values populating this screenshot are coming from a total headcount measure created. What I'm trying to do is create a separate measure that will show when the "TenureMonths" is less than the "DealMonth." So if the TenureMonths is 5, then after DealMonth of 5, the value would be 0. Is this possible?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FYU8.png)

I should add the following information.

"DealMonth" - Comes from the FactData table

"TenureMonths" - Comes from the DimSalesStart table

These two tables are joined by name. I feel like I'm so close because I can see what I want. The second image below is a copy/paste of the pivot table result but with my edits to show what I'd want to have shown. Basically, if(TenureMonths >= DealMonth,1,0). The trouble seems to be that since they're in two different tables, I can't make it work. The rows in the fact table are transactions, but the rows in the dim table are just the people with their start and end dates.

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHI3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some IF([measure1]<[measure2],blank(),[measure1]), however without seeing more of the data it will be hard to guide you specifically.

However you need to create two separate measures, one for TenureMonths and one for DealMonth, depending on the data this can be done with an aggregator forumla such as sum, min, max, etc (depends if there will be more than one value).

Then reference those two measures in the formula pattern I mentioned above, and that should give you want you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I added some additional detail to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I added a dimension table for DealMonth itself and joined to my fact table. That allowed me to do the formulas that I needed.